# Simplify, clarify backup for a former iPhone user

Tags: backup, ios

Former iPhone user, 5 months with Droid (Samsung Galaxy S 5, AT&T). I'd like clarity about backing up. The process is no longer centralized, so (sorry) either is my question.

How do I safekeep my apps, app data, settings, email accounts, wifi settings, tweaks, wallpapers...music, photos, contacts safe in case "something" happens. I think I'd like the simplest most comprehensive options for now.

I have my eye on Titanium eventually. Of course that means rooting, and before I'd do that I'd...need...to...back up my data.

Comment: You may take a look at [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices?rq=1). The answers feature a backup using ADB (Android Debugging Bridge) to create backups as easy as possible.

Comment: The link that *GiantTree* mentioned also has an app called [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) mentioned in an answer, if you prefer the GUI more than the command line.